# Did everything just get wiped out?

Tags: bug

Is it only on my end, or did everything on EESE just disappear?

Comment: I think it's you, or it has been fixed in the meantime. What do you mean "wiped out"? Like, no question at all in the list?

Comment: Yeah, it literally said 0 questions and the list was completely blank. Seems to be back now though

Comment: We can rebuild the website where 90% of the questions are something about Lithium batteries.

Comment: Probably a cookie thing, I've had similar issues in the past, one time the bar said I had gotten +10k rep change in one day

Answer (score 14):

## Nothing to see here. Please look at this LED.

[image: Will Smith in the movie "Men in Black"]